# How may I watch for the creation of a particular "trigger file"?

Tags: shell-script, files, monitoring, executable

I need to create a shell script that executes an application when a file called `start` is created in a particular directory.

How may I write a shell script that waits for the creation of a file with a certain name in a certain location?

Comment: I don't think the question is _actually_ about how to create a file called `start` but  how to trigger a script when a file appears with a certain name. Am I right?

Comment: Yes @Kusalananda, correct!!

Comment: @kumarshivam I reworded the question. Hopefully you will be ok with the new wording.

Comment: How frequently would you be comfortable re-checking for this file's existence? milliseconds? minutes? days?

Comment: Wouldn't inotify be a good candidate for this.

Comment: We should clarify the operating environment here -- @kumar, what OS does this need to run on?

Comment: +1 to the previous two comments: inotify would be a good solution but it is Linux-specific. If applicable, then install the inotify-tools package (if necessary) and see the man page for `inotifywait`.

Answer (score 2):

If your system has `inotifywait` (most Linux distributions, OpenBSD and possibly others), as others have mentioned the least resource-intensive approach is to use `inotifywait`:

```
rm -f yourdirectory/start
while [ "$(inotifywait -e create -q --format %f yourdirectory)" != "start" ]; do :; done
yourcommand
```

That will ensure the `start` file is removed from `yourdirectory`, then wait for its creation, and then run `yourcommand`. `-e create` specifies that we’re only interested in creation events, `-q` specifies that we don’t want `inotifywait`’s diagnostic messages, and `--format %f` specifies that we only want to see the created file’s name in the output.

If you don’t have `inotifywait`, the following will work too, with a delay of at most one second:

```
rm -f yourdirectory/start
while [ ! -e yourdirectory/start ]; do sleep 1; done
yourcommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the tool 'inoticoming' for watching a directory for change.  has logging and pid-file creation.  you can run command on change with additional 'action-options' it's pretty decent :)

i also remember a tool called 'fileschanged' but never got to play with it, could be worth a look.  -Jay